# Changing App Layout Drawer persistent to temporary at media change in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

I have an App Layout of angular components in my AngularDart project. How can I change the `drawer` of App layout from `persistent` to `temporary` at the change of media screen?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `onResize` event on the window to listen change on it and set your layout to `temporary` or `persistent`

```
import "dart:html";
import "dart:async";

StreamSubscription<Event> subscription = window.onResize.listen((Event e) {
  final width = window.screen.width;
});

// onDestroy
subscription.cancel();
```

Comment: Error: The type of 'subscription' can't be inferred because of the use of the instance getter 'onResize'.

Comment: // onDestroy
subscription.cancel();  'subscription' invalid constructor name